# List Controller Methods and their Authorize Attributes or Lack Thereof

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I'd like to build a security check module that we'd add to our projects to inject an overlay when security issues are found and the website is in debug mode.

The first example of this I'd like to try is to list Controllers and Methods that do not have an Authorize Attribute (or extensions of Authorize Attributes) set.

Is there an easy way to obtain a list of the Controllers/Methods with their Authorize Attributes (Some are custom), or lack of them?

Primary goal is to make sure that each Method has one set, even if it is Allow Anonymous, thus forcing the developers to recognize they have methods exposed/unprotected.

If there are other, better ways to achieve this I'd like to hear them as well, but I like the idea of having an on page indicator. EX: "3 Methods lack Authorization Attributes and are exposed to users".

Answer (score 1):

It would be difficult to get you a complete answer that would fit your bill, but you can easily write a security controller that checks the rest of your pages/methods (or run in application start up).  Here is some sample code to help you get started:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var x=asm.GetTypes()
  .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type)) //filter controllers
  .Where(controller=>controller.CustomAttributes.Any(ca=>ca.AttributeType.Name=="TranslateFilter"))
  .Where(controller=>controller.Name!="Translation")
  .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
  .Where(method => method.IsPublic && !method.IsDefined(typeof(NonActionAttribute)))
  .Where(method=>method.ReturnType.Name=="ActionResult")
  .Where(method=>method.CustomAttributes.All(ca => ca.AttributeType.Name != "HttpPostAttribute"))
  .Select(t=>new {Action=t.Name,Controller=t.ReflectedType.Name.Replace("Controller", "")});
```

This was taken from a custom translation engine I wrote.  Many of the conditions in here don't apply, but I've left them in for you to get some ideas on what else you can do, and how to do it.  It's specifically looking for controllers that have the `TranslateFilter` attribute, and isn't a controller named `Translation`, is a public method, returns a type of `ActionResult` and doesn't have the attribute `HttpPostAttribute`.

Comment: You could, conditionally include code like this in the application startup if it's running in debug mode.  Then throw an exception if necessary, stating the controller/action that is violation of your rules. `Debug.Assert(!x.Any(),String.Format("Method {0} in Controller {1} violates my awesome rule",x.First().Action,x.First().Controller));`